# Me da error en este caso el código

Tags: c++

Este es mi 3 caso de mi código en c++ este caso me da error tengo que crear un menú que me de varias opciones con dos variables donde me diga si esos dos números son primos ,pares o impares ,cuál es mayor y me de la opción de salir

```
introducir el código aquí

  break;
case 3: // Verificar si los números son impares o pares
  if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
    cout << "El primer número es par" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "El primer número es impar" << endl;
  }

  if (num2 % 2 == 0) {
    cout << "El segundo número es par" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "El segundo número es impar" << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te recomiendo que te tomes tu tiempo en redactar bien la pregunta. No queda claro por que esta muy mal redactada. Además solo pones una parte del código que, de echo, no hay ningún error aquí. Redacta mejor tu pregunta y muestra más codigo, detalla que estas buscando hacer y donde falla y intenta averiguar el porqué. Un saludo.

Comment: A mi también me da error tu código, me dice que `introducir` no es el nombre de un tipo y que ni `num1` ni `num2` existen entre otros muchos errores.